# MySQL Error codes 1064 and 2014 in stored procedures

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

I'm new to MySQL and trying to write some MySQL stored procedures and encountering some errors which I can't find a fix.

A simple stored procedure to reproduce the errors

```
DELIMITER //
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS testing;
CREATE PROCEDURE testing(sqlQuery varchar(100))
BEGIN
PREPARE stmt FROM sqlQuery;
EXECUTE stmt ;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
END //
DELIMITER ;
```

I'm constructing the dynamic sql query on the application server and sending it as a parameter to the MySQL database server.

For simplicity, let's consider the sqlQuery contains `SELECT * FROM Users`.

When I first execute the stored procedure in the MySQL Workbench, I get:

```
Error Code: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'sqlQuery; EXECUTE stmt ; DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt; END' at line 5
```

When I execute it second time, I get:

```
Error Code: 2014 Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now
```

I can't find a reason behind those errors. Can someone provide some info? Thanks.

---

MySQL: 8.0.19

MySQL Workbench: 8.0.19

Comment: That error can't be coming from the procedure you show. It says that there's a line like `q;` in the procedure.

Comment: Tip - if you're new to MySQL, don't start with SP. They are hard to debug, even when you get the right one. Their usefulness is also significantly overstated, especially by teachers who don't do.

Comment: @Barmar I'm sorry, I have changed the parameter name to more meaningful name in the post but copied the error from the console without changing the parameter name from `q` to `sqlQuery`.

Comment: @danblack Even if you have years of experience with MySQL, you shouldn't be using stored procedures either. :-)

Comment: in addition, the version control aspect is often overlooked. As new accesses try to use existing methods the resulting SQL efficiency goes down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use local variables in the stored procedures. You have to use user variables for prepared statements.

[Local variable scope and resolution](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/local-variable-scope.html)

> Because local variables are in scope only during stored program
>   execution, references to them are not permitted in prepared statements
>   created within a stored program. Prepared statement scope is the
>   current session, not the stored program, so the statement could be
>   executed after the program ends, at which point the variables would no
>   longer be in scope.

So, just reassign the parameter to a user variable.

```
DELIMITER //
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS testing;
CREATE PROCEDURE testing(sqlQuery varchar(100))
BEGIN
SET @a = sqlQuery;
PREPARE stmt FROM @a;
EXECUTE stmt ;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
END //
DELIMITER ;
```

This should work

Answer (score 2):

MYSQL wants [user variables for prepared statements](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/prepare.html):

> A statement prepared in stored program context cannot refer to stored procedure or function parameters or local variables because they go out of scope when the program ends and would be unavailable were the statement to be executed later outside the program. As a workaround, refer instead to user-defined variables, which also have session scope.

So you need an intermediate assignment:

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS testing;

DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE testing(sqlQuery varchar(100))
BEGIN
    SET @sql = sqlQuery;
    PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
    EXECUTE stmt;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
END //

DELIMITER ;
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/dZE8UovAvgzYvFiGdKEkFh/0)**